# Java file writing problems

Tags: java, file-io, zip4j

I am having an issue in Java with file creation. Here is my code -

```
ArrayList<File> list = new ArrayList<File>();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(/*classpathRoot + */"list.txt", "UTF-8");
            writer.println("");
            writer.close();
            list.add(new File("list.txt"));
            ZipParameters args = new ZipParameters();
            args.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_STORE);
            args.setEncryptFiles(true);
            args.setEncryptionMethod(Zip4jConstants.ENC_METHOD_AES);
            args.setAesKeyStrength(Zip4jConstants.AES_STRENGTH_256);
            args.setPassword(keys);
            ZipOutputStream outputStream = null;
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            File out = new File("list.txt");
            outputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(/*classpathRoot + */"data/" + NewUser.ufield.getText() + ".zip"));
            outputStream.putNextEntry(out, args);
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(out);
            byte[] readBuff = new byte[4096];
            int readLen = -1;
            while ((readLen = inputStream.read(readBuff)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(readBuff, 0, readLen);
            }
            outputStream.closeEntry();
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.finish();
            outputStream.close();
```

The problem I am having is that when I am in eclipse, the text file is created, but outside of eclipse it is not. The zip file never even creates, in eclipse or not. Got any tips?

I get the following Exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: data/eduyjd.zip (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:110)
at main.NewUserHandler.actionPerformed(NewUserHandler.java:49)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3311)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

edit: updated code and exception, text files write in both eclipse and outside, zip files still do not write

Comment: Do you get any kind of errors when you run this outside of Eclipse?

Comment: yeah, this http://pastebin.com/i7qa88QQ @Makoto

Comment: Also, did you check what is the content of classLoader.getResource("").getPath()? My gut feeling hints that the problem might be there.

Comment: `new File("list.txt")`? Not `new File(classpathRoot + "/list.txt")`?

Comment: What is this line `NewUserHandler.java:32`? It seems that you pass `null` into a `File` constructor there.

Comment: new error @Tom http://pastebin.com/yMGfh87c

Comment: @Tom is the "new File" line, I guess...

Comment: @AlessandroSantini This one `new File(classLoader.getResource("").getPath())`? According to the JavaDoc of `URL` (`getResource("")` return `URL`) `getPath` would return an empty String if there is something wrong. So I don't think that this is the source :(.

Comment: @Tom, the exception stacktrace points at the File class constructor...

Comment: @Jax "Suddently" you get a new Exception? Btw it is `FileNotFoundException: data/5236.zip (No such file or directory)`, so it can't find a certain file.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6KVi9pvY @Tom

Comment: yeah I realized that, guess Zip4j was trying to add files to a zip I though it would also initialize @Tom

Comment: @AlessandroSantini And? His code contains two calls of that constructor, both with Strings and both with not `null` (as I said, according to the JavaDoc of URL). I don't get your point.

Comment: Wouldn't you use `classPathRoot.getAbsolutePath()` instead of just `classPathRoot` since `classPathRoot` is a file object not a string object?

Comment: @Tom I was updating the code throughout, my exception changed because I changed stuff, I have updated the OP with my current code and exception

Comment: I have dropped that part of the code @Seth

Comment: @Jax, you pasted the code twice :)

Comment: oops gimme a sec @Seth

Comment: @Jax, its the same error. The zip loader cannot find the file you are trying to manipulate. Using `classPathRoot.getAbsolutePath()` will return the string reference to the folder, then adding ` + */"data/" + NewUser.ufield.getText() + ".zip"` will add the extra information directing it to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
outputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(/*classpathRoot + */"data/" + NewUser.ufield.getText() + ".zip"));
```

this points to non-existing file... see if `data` folder exists ;) that can cause it

```
File folder = new File("data");
if (!folder.exists())
    folder.mkdir();
```